# Check Whether duplicate rows are added to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, duplicates

I have two forms Form1(DGV1) and Form2(DGV2) with Datagridview control on both the forms.

On Form1 there is a button link to Form2 where user can add rows to Form1 datagridview(DGV1) ..In Form2 Datagridview there is a checkbox in the first column and the user can select only one row at a time.There are two button on Form2 1) Done 2) Add Items

When user clicks on Add Items by selecting the rows one after another,the rows must be added to the datagridview on Form1 and when Done button is clicked Form 1 should be displayed with all the rows that are added.

I have achieved this using the below code:

```
int inde x= objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add(); 
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows[index]; 
decimal UnitCos = Convert.ToDecimal(gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString()); row[0] = false; 
row[1] = 1;
row[2] = gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
row[3] = LoadSellQty();
row[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
row[5] = LoadSellQty() * UnitCost; 
row[7] = Convert.ToInt32(gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

Now the problem is to validate if the same row is added into DGV1 on Form1 when AddItems button is clicked on Form2.I mean no duplicate rows must be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a unique name from your `DataGridView` rows, you can achieve this by using `linq`

```
bool IsExist = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                   .Count(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Cells[colIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()) &&
                                   c.Cells[colIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Trim() == dgv[colIndex, rowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()) > 1;

if (IsExist)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

**UPDATE** base on `ItemID`

```
bool IsExist = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                      .Count(c => 
                      c.Cells[colIndexOfItemId]
                      .EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == ItemID) > 1; //or (int)c.Cells[colIndexOfItemId].Value
```

Comment: hi..I have a unique column called ItemID..so may be I can check that using your Code.I will try and let you know.

Comment: Dude, one more problem is..Suppose I have added a row to the Form1 datagridview from Form2 by clicking AddItems button ..then Done button.Suppose I wanted to add another row by clicking on the link button in Form1 which takes me to Form2..Now the gridview gets empty and a completely new row is added.So i want to know how if ROW1 is added to Form1 DGV and clicked on DONE button...and again if I want to add another row ROW2.Both Row1 and Row2 shud exist but that is not happening.How to achieve this.

Comment: I guess your problem about on how to check the exist `itemId` is already solved. in your second problem.. am sorry to say but i can't figure out on what are you trying to accomplish. but you can rephrase your question about that. :)

Comment: Yeah it is solved.Thanks mate.What i wanted to accomplish is..When I am adding a row to the DGV1 from FORM2 and click on Done button..I will be displaying the Form1 DGV1.Ok.Now again if I want to add another row to the DGV1 from FORM2..the already existing row is not stored..Hope u got it

Comment: let me put it in a Simple way  Form1 - DGV1  Button1(link to Form2)
Form2 - AddItems(button2) Done(button3) DGV2.Now when i click on Button1 it goes to Form2.Now I add a row ROW1 to DGV1 after selecting a row from DGV2 and click on button2.Then click on Done button to show Form1.So we have Row1 in DGV1.Now if I wanted to add another row ROW2  to DGV1 from form2.I repeat the process..but the problem is ROW1 which was added earlier no longer exists.I think this is clear.

Comment: I have created a datatable to store existing rows.Thanks mate.Solved the issue.StackOverFlow has got quality members.I am a member of many forums.So far I can say this is the best.

Comment: you're welcome indeed this the best and this is not just like a forum, by the way, to better for rephrasing your another problem is you can create another question for that and for more clarification and better format so we can more understand to read. `:)`

Comment: Not a problem..just creating a  datatable and adding the existing rows to it has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would try two different way as follow and btw I prefer solution #2:

1. Simply write a loop myself if the row count is small, just check value one by one, which makes the code looks not that good.
2. If your are using DataSet or DataTable, try add a UniqueConstraint on to the DataTable which actually contains all columns, so if duplicate row been added it will throw exception and you know it. For more detail check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35.aspx).

Comment: Hi..As you can see from the code I am not using any dataset or datatable directly creating a row and adding it to the other grid on Form1.So any other suggestions.Thank you.

Comment: Well my guess is even if you are binding to DataTable even indirectly adding data might raise the same exception.

Comment: Hi Simon..this code worked objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Count(c => c.Cells[7].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == ItemID) > 0). But want to maintain rows in datagridview as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dgViewOrderList_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && dgViewOrderList.CurrentCell.Value != null)
            {
                var cellValue = dgViewOrderList.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                var isExist = dgViewOrderList.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Count(c =>c.Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == cellValue) > 1;
                if (isExist)
                {
                    dgViewOrderList.CurrentCell.Value = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```